# Database does not exist but the Query was completed with errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm connected to the database, the query ran it created a table but I got this error message.

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Database 'E:/SQLGISDATA/taxpayer.mdf' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

This is the code that I used:

```
USE [E:/SQLGISDATA/taxpayer.mdf]
GO

SELECT * 
INTO VISION_LAND11
FROM [TOMSQLVISION].[VISION_2021].[REAL_PROP].[LAND]
```

Comment: More info. Have you checked the docs on [Use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? What is the relevance of `TOMSQLVISION` query to the error?

Comment: I think what may be happening is that your first `USE` statement failed.  You are telling it to look for a file at the file system location `E:/SQLGISDATA/taxpayer.mdf`.  The system is telling you that that file is not there. So, it did not changes the DB context, but continued in the current context to execute the  `SELECT` statement successfully.

Comment: Errors in SQL Server rarely abort the whole connection. In this case the first batch failed and then the second ran in whatever database context was already in place

Comment: The USE itself looks very confused though. You need to attach the mdf file to then reference it as a database or reference the database by its name, not filepath, if it is already attached

Comment: It should be **USE [DatabaseName]**